# Select items by ID from another list of items - Local sequence cannot be used in LINQ to SQL

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql

I am getting this error while I try to obtain a list of items from a table that are referenced in another table. The equivalent of the third line:

```
select ID_CLIENT from tb_client where cli_nom = 'John Doe'
select ClientAdresseID from tb_client_adresse where clientId = 3120 -- returns items 342, 343, 344
select * from tb_client_adresse_type where clientAdresseId IN (342, 343, 344)
```

I wrote this simple LINQ query using two lambda expressions:

```
var clientAddresseTypes =
    DataContext.ClientAdresseTypes.Where(x => clientAdresses.Any(y => y.ClientAdresseID == x.ClientAdresseID)).ToList();
```

Unfortunately, I get a run-time error:

> Local sequence cannot be used in LINQ to SQL implementation of query
>   operators except the Contains() operator

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @JAT, using `Contains()` would require to change the query quite a bit, no?

Comment: Yes I deleted the comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I have figured this out. Since it's not possible to use `.Any()` in LINQ-to-SQL, we have to make two LINQ queries instead of one.

The first to obtain a list of IDs that have to be matched by the predicate of the second query:

```
IList<int> clientAddressIds = clientAdresses.Select(clientAddress => clientAddress.ClientAdresseID).ToList();
```

The second query to actually obtain a list of items that we wanted in the first place:

```
IList<ClientAdresseType> clientAddresseTypes = DataContext.ClientAdresseTypes.Where(clientAddressType => clientAddressIds.Contains(clientAddressType.ClientAdresseID)).ToList();
```